# MUI TextField with multiline - warning about missing id/name

Tags: reactjs, input, material-ui, material-design, textfield

I have this issue that as soon as I add "multiline" to my Material UI (MUI) TextField, my browser shows a warning "*A form field element should have an id or name attribute*". It works all right, but the warning indicates something is off. As soon as I remove the "multiline" the warning is gone.

Anyone who know how to get rid of this warning?

```
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";

const StyledTextArea = styled(TextField)(({ theme }) => ({
  "& .MuiInputBase-root": {
    "& .MuiInputBase-colorPrimary": { color: "#001E43" },
  },
  "& label.Mui-focused": {
    color: "#001E43",
  },
  "& .MuiOutlinedInput-root": {
    "&.Mui-focused fieldset": {
      borderColor: "#001E43",
    },
  },
}));

function InputMultipleField({
  type,
  item,
  setItem,
  label,
  guidance,
  maxLength,
  errorNotice,
}) {
  const [guide, setGuide] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div className="mb-4 flex flex-col">
      <div className="mb-2 flex w-full items-center">
        <StyledTextArea
          label={label}
          id={label}
          autoComplete="off"
          type={type}
          inputProps={{ maxLength: maxLength }}
          multiline
          rows={6}
          value={item || ""}
          onChange={(e) => {
            setItem(e.target.value);
          }}
          className="w-full "
          error={!!errorNotice}
          size="small"
        />
       
    </div>
  );
}

export default InputMultipleField;
```

Comment: Can you add your code for your StyledTextArea component?

Comment: Sure, it's just above the function. It's just a styled TextField from MUI

Comment: Are you sure your label field is not being set to null or undefined?

Comment: Yeah, as it's used and visible for the label. I have also used {label ||"randomtextifnull"}, but it give the same warning

Comment: Can you paste the exact browser error?

Comment: A form field element has neither an id nor a name attribute. This might prevent the browser from correctly autofilling the form.
To fix this issue, add a unique id or name attribute to a form field. This is not strictly needed, but still recommended even if you have an autocomplete attribute on the same element.

Comment: Nothing is jumping out at me... Have you inspected the form field on the browser to ensure it's rendering how you expect it to?

Comment: I'm also experiencing this issue   

@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.102”
@mui/material": "^5.14.20”

Any fixes yet ?